# Linux Firefox default sans-serif font

Tags: firefox, browser, fonts, cross-browser

Which font is the default `sans-serif` font in Linux? When I go in Windows in Firefox to Options > Font > Advanced I can see that the default `sans-serif` font is Arial, but in Linux it only shows `sans-serif` as a font by itself.

Any idea how can I check which `sans-serif` font is this?

Comment: Nice question! I thought Firefox's font was a very beautiful one, and it was frustrating not to know its name. Then I found out it's "DejaVu Sans" for those who have it installed.

Answer (score 50):

If fonts are handled by fontconfig then they are defined in /etc/fonts.
It seems the command `fc-match` does the mapping from 'serif', 'sans-serif', etc. to the actual fonts:

```
$ fc-match sans-serif
Vera.ttf: "Bitstream Vera Sans" "Roman"
$ fc-match monospace
VeraMono.ttf: "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" "Roman"
```

Comment: +1. FWIW mine was `NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular"` in Arch Linux.

Comment: `DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"` in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Awesome! This helped me lay out a document downloaded from Google Docs because the download does not have my browser font stored that I used in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

The sans-serif font will be an open-source alternative to the proprietary fonts you may be accustomed to.

As a generalisation, Linux distributions have support for TrueType fonts like Lucida, Helvetica and Arial, but you have to download them separately - they don't come pre-installed.

for example, [see this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-True-Type-Fonts-on-Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Most modern GNU/Linux distributions, like OpenSuSE and Fedora for example, use [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) for fonts management and configuration. The configuration is stored in `/etc/fonts/` and it's sub-directories. There will be a mapping file there, but the name of the file varies from distribution to distribution and from version to version. For example in OpenSuSE 12.3 you can find default mappings in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/58-suse-post-user.conf`

Comment: Agreed. Firefox for Linux (at least version 28) depends on the system language setting for selecting the script type (English is for example: Western). Unless the distro has configured that section it shows simply `Serif: serif` etc. On most Linux distros fontconfig determines the default serif etc. in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`. On Slackware for example it selects in  `45-latin.conf` DejaVu. BTW on my system the command `fc-match`, did **not** show the default font.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't such a thing as THE linux, each ships with a different set of fonts. you might already know that sans serif refers to a family of fonts...

Comment: I know sans-serif is a family of fonts, but it seems that in Linux you can use that directly as the name of a font in Firefox.

I'm not sure if it's always the same font, if it's defined in some place to which font it corresponds or if it depends on the distribution and every distribution puts an arbitrary font called "sans-serif" that may be anything.